# Joint probability mass function of two orthogonal discrete random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Assume $X$ and $Y$ are geometric random variables on $\{0,1,2,...\}$ with parameters $p$ and $r$ respectively. Assume also that they are orthogonal, i.e. $\mathbb{E}[XY]=0$. Can we compute their joint probability mass function $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \mathbb{P} (X=x, Y=y)$ where $x,y \in \{0,1,...\}$? Or how to compute $\mathbb{P}(X\leq Y)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a cute but strange problem.

If $p+r\le1$, the following joint distribution mass function fits the bill:
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}1-p-r&\text{if} x=y=0\\
(1-p)p^x&\text{if }x>0, y=0\\(1-r)r^y&\text{if }x=0,y>0\\
0&\text{otherwise, that is, if }x>0,y=0.\end{cases}$$
From this one checks that $P(Y>X)=(1-r)\sum_{y=1}^\infty r^y = r$ and hence $P(X\le Y)=(1-p-r)+r=1-p$.

If $p+r>1$ there is no joint distribution with the desired properties.

The quirky thing about this problem is that the constraint $E[XY]=0$ implies that the joint event $[X>0,Y>0]$ must have probability zero, that is, $f(x,y)=0$ for $x>0,y>0$.  To make the margins come out correctly, all the row and column sums of the 2-dimensional array $f(x,y)$ must match the corresponding marginal distributions for $X$ and for $Y$; the forced zeros when $x>0, y>0$ make this matching easy.  Only the value of $f(0,0)$ fails to drop out immediately.  The requirement that the double sum must evaluate to $1$ gives the formula $f(0,0)=1-p-r$; the requirement that $f(0,0)\ge0$ gives rise to the restriction  that $p+r\le1$.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ and $Y$ are non-negative and so is $XY$. If $EXY=0$ the we must have $XY=0$ with probability $1$. Hence $X\neq 0$ implies $Y=0$. So $P(X=x,Y=y)=0$ of $x\neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$. We we only need $P(X=0, Y=y)$ and $P(X=x, Y=0)$. But these two probabilities cannot be determined with the given information. $P(X \leq Y)$ also cannot be determined.